# Stateless React how to pass key

Tags: reactjs

I am unsure how to pass a key to a stateless react component

```
MyComponent: (props) => {
        return(<span>{props.somevalue}</span>);
    }


aCollection.map((value,index)=> <MyComponent somevalue={value});
```

Doing this will result in the key warning.

So I tried to pass in key via a prop

```
aCollection.map((value,index)=> <MyComponent key={index} somevalue={value});


MyComponent: (props) => {
            return(<span key={this.props.key} >{props.somevalue}</span>);
     }
```

However I get the error
https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/special-props.html

How am I meant to pass/use the key in my stateless component?

Comment: Remove `key={this.props.key}`, it will work without it.

Comment: But shouldn't I be setting the key for internal react to work correctly?

Comment: As far as I know, setting it on `<MyComponent />` is enough to help React.

Answer (score 2):

According to React docs, a key should be provided for list component items.

You only need pass the `key` to react component, you don't need to use it in the component, like access the key with `props.key`.

check out [Basic List Component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#basic-list-component).

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

```
<React.Fragment key={item.id}>{SomeFunctionComponent(item)}</React.Fragment>
```

From the docs:

> Fragments declared with the explicit  syntax may have keys.

Can be found [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)

Answer (score 0):

As the error says that special props `(ref and key)` which are used by React, and are thus not forwarded to the component, so you can't pass the prop by name `key` and yes in order to eliminate warning you need to define the key, so just rename the prop while sending it to MyComponent. Also I believe you must use the prop in your stateless component like `props.index` and not `this.props.index`.

```
aCollection.map((value,index)=> <MyComponent index={index} somevalue={value});


MyComponent: (props) => {
            return(<span key={props.index} >{props.somevalue}</span>);
     }
```

You only need to define key to the span so use it as  `key={props.index}`. It should eliminate the warning.

Comment: Did my answer help in solving your problem