# Functional Stateless Components and Keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do you Map a key in a functional component, precisely the 'key' keyword, not just a general index?

I'm using Map in one functional component to create a list of another element, but when I use 'key' to remove the console warning the code breaks.

I can switch the included props to 'index' and get working code, but then get the warning that I am missing a 'key' index in a list.

As per: [Stateless React how to pass key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40412072/stateless-react-how-to-pass-key)

The answer provided does not explain how to pass the specific case of a 'key' (note the keyword key rather than a general index) to a functional component.

```
// results in an undefined key ie: key=''
const ComponentOne = ({records}) => (
  {records.map( (record, index) => <ComponentTwo data={record} key={index}/>)}
);

const ComponentTwo = ({data, key}) =>
  <div key={key}>
    {data}
  </div>

// This method works but comes with the console warning for a 'missing key'
const ComponentOne = ({records}) => (
  {records.map( (record, index) => <ComponentTwo data={record} index={index}/>)}
);

const ComponentTwo = ({data, index}) =>
  <div key={index}>
    {data}
  </div>
```

https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

This link also discusses why using an index as a key is an antipattern, so I'm breaking the rules if I use 'index', but functional components don't allow for the use of 'key' as it's a particular keyword with significant meaning.

Comment: What's your question exactly?

Comment: How would I use the 'key' keyword in a functional component so I can both remove the console warning and get the key in the second component?

Comment: I don't think you need to forward the key to whatever your functional component renders. Plus, `key` is one of the few props that aren't transferable, IIRC.

Comment: just use the `key` on the Component itself, you do not need to pass it down

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings when I do that I get compilation errors, its a functional component so `props` doesn't exist either

Comment: you do not need to have   <div key={key}>.  <ComponentTwo data={record} key={index}/> is enough unless you want to use key for some other purposes. Using index as key is anti pattern but if it is your only option then go for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like that

```
    const ComponentOne = ({records}) => (
      <React.Fragment>
       {records.map( (record, index) => <ComponentTwo data={record} key={index}/>)}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
```

You can also pass a unique property from `records` as key, like `id` or something like.